# jquery, attribute selector, get current attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, selector

I have an input:

```
<input type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" decimals="2">
```

where "decimals" could be a value from 0 to 4.

In the onblur event, whatever number the user types in will be changed to conform, thus:

```
decimals="2"
User enters: 123.456
Input is changed to: 123.46
```

That's trivial, no problem. My question is about the most efficient way to get the value of "decimals." Ordinarily, I'd write (jquery):

```
$('[decimals]').blur(function(){
    val = $(this).attr('decimals');
    // *** do stuff with val ***
});
```

...but it seems to me there ought to be a more efficient way to get the value of "decimals" since we've already selected the input based on that attribute. Is there, or is my code as written the only way?

Comment: If you're using custom attributes at least use *valid* custom attributes, using the `data-*` prefix, such as `data-decimals`, which can be retrieved in plain JavaScript with `elementReference.dataset.decimals`, or in jQuery with: `$(elementReference).data('decimals');`

Comment: are you talking about `$(this)`? you cannot avoid it if want to call `$.attr`, but thats almost free (jQuery cache) but you can read value with `this.getAttribute('decimals')` also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look to [attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes). This is a [NamedNodeMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NamedNodeMap) with some functions.

If you are referring to attributes and not to [custom data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) you can do:

```js
$(function () {
  $('[decimals]').blur(function(){
    var val = this.attributes.decimals.value;
    var val1 = this.attributes.getNamedItem('decimals').value;
    var val2 = this.getAttribute('decimals');
    
    console.log('this.attributes.decimals.value = ' + val);
    console.log('this.attributes.getNamedItem("decimals").value = ' + val1);
    console.log('this.getAttribute("decimals") = ' + val);
    // *** do stuff with val ***
  }).trigger('blur');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" decimals="2">
</form>
```

Instead if you are referring to custom data attributes:

> decimals="2"
>
> User enters: 123.456
>
> Input is changed to: 123.46

You can do:

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-decimals]').on('blur', function(e){
    var val = +$(this).data('decimals');

    var txtNumber = +this.value;

    this.value = txtNumber.toFixed(2);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input type="number" size="5" maxlength="5" data-decimals="2">
</form>
```

Comment: So, to sum up, there's not a way to get the attribute value without asking for it in some way inside the function, no shortcuts. My question was largely informational, hoping to learn something new. Thank you.